# Reusable edit form in Apache Wicket

Tags: components, wicket, panel, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a simple ContactEditPanel which contains a form and a number of textfields. Up until now I included an AjaxSubmitLink in this panel which, if the form content is valid, saves/updates the Contact instance contained in the Panel model. So far so simple. However now I'd like to remove the link in order that I may, depending on the context in which I use the ContactEditPanel, place the submit link at different levels of my overall component hierarchy. For instance in one context I'd like to use to flip between ContactEditPanel and ContactViewPanel with a bar of actions above the current view (edit | save , cancel). Another context would be to use ContactEditPanel in a standalone way (maybe part of a multi-step process) with just a save link below.

I was contemplating refactoring my ContactEditPanel to extends FormComponentPanel rather than Panel as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/GIaAAQ) but I'm not sure whether this is the right approach and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Many Thanks,

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the panel like a FormComponent so extend FormComponentPanel, it will allow you to keep all the validation you write contained to the component and also allow you to reuse it as you wish.

Just think of it as you've created a new FormComponent, like a TextField or DropDownChoice.